# HashMap first key is null

Tags: java, android, arrays, hashmap

i'am using hasmap and LinkedHasmap for a while but now in this situation is acting strang, i'am adding to a hasmap a key and and a value from 2 array's with the same size in this case with size=4, but the hasmap is putting the first key as null in the debbuging i see it will overwrite the the second key in the same position has the first, it never has the same key and never the same has so i cant understand whats happening.

The hasmap is declared has a field.

```
    private HashMap<String, String> courses = new HasMap<String, String>();
```

And in this method i want to fill the hasMap:

```
private void coursesInit(int coursesListSize) {

    for (int j = 0; j < coursesListSize; j++) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        LinearLayout inserPoint = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_inside_left);

        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.courses_button_left_drawer,
                null);

        Button btnTag = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.course_id);
        btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        if (coursesIdList.isEmpty()) {
            btnTag.setText("Your Course " + (j + 1));
            btnTag.setId(j);

        } else {
            btnTag.setText(coursesNamesList.get(j));
            btnTag.setId(Integer.parseInt(coursesIdList.get(j)));

        // Populate LinkedHasMap in the correct order where Key=
        // course_id && Value= course_fullname
        courses.put(coursesIdList.get(j), coursesNamesList.get(j));

        }

        if (j != 0) {
            btnTag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_inside);
        }

        row.addView(view);

        inserPoint.addView(row, 3);
    }

}
```

I also had tried with just Map and LinkedHasMap and inside a method with just a for looping the array's but its the same resut.

The debbuging screenshots:

courses HasMap:
[Courses Hasmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqqjl.png)

Arrays:
[Arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6drs3.png)

Comment: you are inflating a view in a for loop and you have initialization also in the for loop which is not good

Comment: from your snippets of code I can't determine where is a problem. Please, post additional relevant code

Comment: Yes i now, this method was just for tests but for sure the initialization should be outside my mistake thks ;)

Answer (score 3):

If your problem is that the `table[0]` element of the `HashMap` instance is `null` in the debugger, then this is NOT a problem as long as `HashMap` works as explained in the documentation (which it does). Internal implementation details should not matter for you (it's a black box for you to use). If you want to retreive the keys of the map, use `HashMap#entrySet`.

See following example of a single insertion in a HashMap and the resulting `HashMap#table` field:

```
 final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
 map.put("One", "1");
```

[image]

As you can see, the element is inserted at `table[12]`.

Also keep in mind [`HashMap` allows null as key](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), so if you set key as null, this is a valid key.

Comment: It seems more likely the *actual* problem is that there are four values in the arraylists(id/name), and only three entries in the hashmap. I think the `null` is just a red herring. Of course, we don't know if `coursesListSize` actually reflects the correct size from this snippet.

Comment: But the Hasmap table should has my lost key? in this case key=6 value= Sistemas operativos? If i do a courses.get("6") the hasmap will retrieve the correct value?

Comment: Which lost key? How do you know the key is lost? `table` indexes are not your keys. Expand the map Entry and you can see the keys and their value. Or call `HashMap#entrySet` and you can check there.

Comment: Thanks Moskito you are right it's a black box indeed, i tried now courses.get and everything is in the right place, my error was not to try because in the debug i cant see it so i never tried. Its a newbie mystake sorry guys and thanks for the time

Comment: Yes but before you alert me in my mind the table index was my keys now reading with more focus the hasmap docs i understand